# Update string with interpolation for each using

Tags: c#, string, interpolation

I have code like this:

```
int i = 1;
string dynemicString = $"i = {i}";

while(i<10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
}
```

And I want to get result like this:

```
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
```

...

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i = 1;

while(i<10)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
    i++;
}
```

For more information read about [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

If you want a more tokenized way of doing this, use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int i = 1;
string dynemicString = "i = {0}";

while(i<10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(dynemicString,i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Actually : the second method will return the value 0 all the time !

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach to TheGeneral's answer. I'm not suggesting *using* it, but I find it an "interesting" idea just for the sake of learning a bit more about how string interpolation works.

When an interpolated string literal is converted to a `string`, all the expressions are immediately evaluated and the string is formatted. The string can't change afterwards.

When an interpolated string literal is converted to a `FormattableString`, the expressions are evaluated, but the string formatting isn't performed. Instead, the results of all the expressions are stored for later formatting. Every time you call `ToString` on a `FormattableString`, the formatting is performed again.

So, we can make it dynamic by making the same values (as evaluated initially) return different strings when string formatting happens. One simple - but really ugly - way of doing that is to use a delegate to capture `i`, and then put the delegate in a wrapper that overrides `ToString` and executes the delegate each time. Here's a complete example of that:

```
// CODE FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY. DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION!
using System;

public class FuncWrapper
{
    private readonly Func<string> func;

    public FuncWrapper(Func<string> func) =>
        this.func = func;

    public override string ToString() => func();
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 1;
        // Capture i in a delegate; each time the delegate
        // is executed, you'll get a different value. Each
        // time ToString is called, the delegate will be called
        var wrapper = new FuncWrapper(() => i.ToString());

        FormattableString dynamicString = $"i = {wrapper}";
        while (i < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dynamicString);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
```